# What is the best practice for a Relation between Accounts with two roles?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm trying to get the best relation between the two roles that one account can have, which are "User" and "Company". I'm deciding between these:

If someone is going to register, he/she needs to choose between what role is going to use, then fill the rest of the fields. For example, If I register as a User, the field "companyId" is going to be empty, and I don't want that...

[image]

The same here, If I register as a company, I need to fill the required fields and that's it, but the field "userId" is empty, in case if I receive any feedback or I put my project.

[image]

So what is the best practice for doing this? You can read the complete "fields" that a [User](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViColombia/blob/master/server/src/entity/User.ts) or [Company](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/TeViColombia/blob/master/server/src/entity/Business.ts) needs to fill.

Comment: Firebase databases (both Realtime Database and Firestore - you haven't said which you are using) are NoSQL and non-relational by nature.  You can't enforce a schema with relationships.  It's up to you to keep any fields up to date, and it's up to you to design your data so that it serves the queries you intend to perform.

Comment: Hey Doug, I want to use firebase with this project with firestore, but I want to keep it as a relationship database (more comfortable for me)

Comment: Ignore the database component then, we only need to discuss conceptual relationships. Explain more of the process, because both are equally valid and invalid for different scenarios, what about user belonging to company? If you are having trouble review this from the other angle, think in terms of 1:many, think of the types of queries and data you are expecting to use, these relationships help govern your structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one raises some questions, for sure.

- Why would `account` be modeled as a child of `feedback` and `project` ?
- Similarly, why would both `user` and `company` be child entities of `account`?

I think those relationships are backwards: Instead of "Accounts have users" make it "Users have accounts". Apply the same to `Account --> Feedback` and `Account --> Project`: Feedback is given on Accounts, and Projects are tied to Accounts. This is close to what you've done in the second diagram, but there are some questions there too:

- What to do with `Company`? Is a `Company` *really* a separate entity from `User`? Or is there a relationship between them?
- Where does `Account` fit into the second diagram?

I would suggest something like this (the fields need to be updated with the correct keys, but the relationships are the important part):

[image: Diagram]

This allows both a `User` and a `Company` to have an `Account`. It also allows `User`'s to be assigned to a `Company`. `Account`'s belong to either a `User` or a `Company`, and both `Project` and `Feedback` are defined in terms of an `Account`.

Also think in terms of the *cardinality* of each of these relationships:

- can a user be associated with more than 1 company? Must **all** users be assigned to a company?
- Can a company have no users?
- Does an account have exactly 1 owner? Can it be owned by both a User and a Company at the same time? Can it have no owner at all?

And some more general questions to consider:

- Does a project exist independently of an account (this might be phrased as "is `Project` a *weak* or a *strong* entity?")?
- Does feedback really apply to an account? Or is feedback actually a property of a User/Company?